# How to choose between getExternalCacheDir and getExternalFilesDir(null) when storing temporary file

Tags: android

I have a use case, where I need to capture an image file using `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent, store it in a temporary location and transfer it over network.

Due to its "temporary" characteristic, I was wondering is it more appropriate for me to store the image file in `getExternalCacheDir`.

However, I have a concern, system might automatic perform "clean up" on cache folder, in the middle of operation.

If such concern is a valid concern, is it more appropriate for me to store the image file in `getExternalFilesDir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [getExternalCacheDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()):

> - The platform does not always monitor the space available in shared storage, and thus may not automatically delete these files. Apps
>     should always manage the maximum space used in this location.
> - **Currently the only time files here will be deleted by the platform is    when running on Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 or later and 
>     Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated(File) returns true.**

Given the nature of file as temporary, you should be quite safe with using `getExternalCacheDir` unless your storage is emulated.

If you wan't to ensure that you need to have these files even on emulated storage then go ahead with `getExternalFilesDir`

Comment: To be paranoid enough, I choose over `getExternalFilesDir`.